# document.domain and cross-site-scripting

Tags: jquery, xss

Debugging assistance requested.

The page http://www.freshfaves.com/newfave.html contains this code:

```
<script>
document.domain = 'freshfaves.com';
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dbUrl = 'http://freshfaves.com/';
    var result = '';
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: dbUrl,
            data: [], //params,
            async: false,
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(d,status) { result = d; return false; },
            error: function(xmlhttp,errmsg) { result = errmsg; return false; }
    });
    alert('result: '+result);
});
</script>
```

To my understanding, the XMLHttpRequest cross-site restraints are checked based on the document.domain value, and that value is set to what is both a valid suffix of the current page url, and an exact match to the site hosting the requested page.

This is a cross-site request, in that www.freshfaves.com and freshfaves.com are on different hosts.  The result is an alert box displaying 'result: error'.  The weblogs on the other site show that the request was not received there, so it apparently errored before the request was sent.

If I change the dbUrl to 'http://www.freshfaves.com/', the request succeeds, so the problem seems closely related to the url, and is not a bug elsewhere in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should not be possible, since basically it is a different domain name, possibly pointing to a completely different server.

EDIT: just noticed the

`document.domain = 'freshfaves.com';`

part. This only works to let two scripts from different (sub)domains communicate, e.g. with *iframes* from different subdomains. Both sides need to set this property to the same domain to communicate. Check out this link with more info on how to make this work: http://ajaxian.com/archives/how-to-make-xmlhttprequest-calls-to-another-server-in-your-domain

There is a draft from W3C that specifies how to handle *cross-origin* requests, which has been (partially) implemented in Firefox 3, and possibly other browsers as well: http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/

I assume you are having trouble when people visit the site with *www* in front of the domain name, but some also omit the *www* part. This can be resolved by dynamically generating your domain name to include the *www* part whether it is present in the URL, or even better, make the URL a relative:

`var dbUrl = '/mylocation';`

Comment: I don't think relative URLs will work for him here because freshfaves.com and www.freshfaves.com seem to be different servers.

Answer (score 0):

All the examples in the available documentation on document.domain such as [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc196989%28VS.85%29.aspx) for IE, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) for Mozilla always have different **sub**domains like images.xyz.com and www.xyz.com, but I have yet to see one in which one request comes from the domain itself, i.e. xyz.com.

Can you  try mapping `freshfaves.com` to, say, `test.freshwaves.com` and see whether your approach works for that?

Comment: I changed from 'dev.freshfaves.com' to 'freshfaves.com' to make the document.domain trick work.  The xmlhttprequest url needs to match the document.domain domain, because of security restrictions, and the document.domain is restricted, in turn, to being a suffix of the current page url.  So making the data-provider url the shorter version 'freshfaves.com' complies with both requirements.